# Indicate of commit message is multiline in git log oneline

Tags: git

I use the following alias to show the git log:

```
[alias]
  ls = log --source --graph --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h %Creset[%ad] %s %C(green)[%an]%C(red)%d'
```

It's basically a modified version `git log --pretty=oneline`.

```
* b928fd3e7aef [2022-11-15] refactor: rename field of Definitions struct [Author Name] (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
* ecf0e00d0fc3 [2022-11-15] feat: deserialize definitions into a custom struct [Author Name]
* 13651af5e52f [2022-11-15] refactor: change library name [Author Name]
* 94f6694b43c2 [2022-11-15] feat: add func for making GET requests to api [Author Name]
* adf64f3dc2a2 [2022-11-15] feat: add enum for representing operation types [Author Name]
* 7df54e9305e7 [2022-11-15] feat: add struct to represent api [Author Name]
* 3bde60087494 [2022-11-14] Initial commit [Author Name]
```

Since the log is shown in single line, it's unclear if a particular commit message spans over multiple lines. If an indicator of sorts marked that this commit has multi-line message, that would be perfect. I don't want to show the body of the commit message. I just want to show a marker *if* the body of the commit message is not empty.

Something like this (note the emoji `^_^` acting as a marker at commit `13651af5e52f` which has a multi-line commit message):

```
* b928fd3e7aef [2022-11-15] refactor: rename field of Definitions struct [Author Name] (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
* ecf0e00d0fc3 [2022-11-15] feat: deserialize definitions into a custom struct [Author Name]
* 13651af5e52f [2022-11-15] refactor: change library name [Author Name] ^_^
* 94f6694b43c2 [2022-11-15] feat: add func for making GET requests to api [Author Name]
* adf64f3dc2a2 [2022-11-15] feat: add enum for representing operation types [Author Name]
* 7df54e9305e7 [2022-11-15] feat: add struct to represent api [Author Name]
* 3bde60087494 [2022-11-14] Initial commit [Author Name]
```

NOTE that by "body" I mean the parts of a commit message after the "subject."

Comment: git already has this - the first empty line in a commit message. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_discussion

Comment: @fredrik I know that. But how does that help me?

Comment: Limit how many characters you write on that first line. You can do that by commit hook. the normal practice is to write a short subject line and then have an empty line and write details. Follow that and you're done.

Comment: @fredrik I know how to write commit messages. My question was about creating an alias for `git log` that showed a marker if the commit message is multi-line. Read the full question, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git has nothing built-in for this, and it's not possible to do it *completely* reliably with a single call to `git log`, but you can get close: use some sort of marker character, e.g., `%x01` or `%x00`, to separate the subject and body and end-of-body:

```
git log --format="%h [%ad] %s%x01%b%x01 [%n] %d"
```

(I left out the color directives for brevity: add them back as desired).

Then, post-process this output by looking for your markers: if the marker character is immediately followed by a second marker, the body was empty, so strip both markers.  If the marker is followed by text before the second marker, that's the body: strip it and the markers and insert your replacement emoji (or whatever) at the end.

That is, pipe the output of `git log` to a small program you write, perhaps just a simple sed or awk script.

Answer (score -3):

If you just want to show commits containing your marker, you could pipe the output through grep, something like:

`git log | grep ^_^`

I'm sure you could modify your alias for git log to search for specific text, but cannot remember the syntax offhand - you could also show multi-line commit body by searching for the backslash n newline character(s) in the body, instead of a marker?